# Lag while drawing in FingerPaint

Tags: android, drawing

When drawing using the [FingerPaint class](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.html), the finger moves ahead of the actual line that is visible on the canvas. Any clues?

Thanks.

Comment: You are testing application on which device / emulator??
Emulator's are often less responsive then real device...

Comment: I am not testing on an emulator, but a real device - Samsung Galaxy Tab.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have apps running in the background that are taking up resources?

I found that someone with the same problem is using an anti-virus app. But I (not an expert!) am not aware of any existing viruses on Android to date so I advised him to try without the anti-virus running...

If anyone can confirm or deny this, I'd appreciate the response :)